# Custom domain and how to access site as http://

Tags: azure, godaddy-api

In Azure, I have purchased a Custom Domain and the configuration has been done automatically - all good till now however the site is accessible only using: www.sitename.com

If I access it using http://sitename.com only, it is not working.

For info, I tried to remove the CNAME however didnt allow.

Suppose I dont want to use the wwww, how can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically you'd add an A record that points to the IP address of your site. What are you running your site on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access your website with http://sitename.com, you have to create the A record and enable the A record mapping in the app. For how to map an A record, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-an-a-record) is for your reference.
1.Copy the app's IP address
[image]
2.Create the A record

- An A record to map to the app's IP address.
- A TXT record to map to the app's default hostname. 
  [image]
  3.Enable the A record mapping in the app
  [image]

The custom domain you configured is not secured. You'd better click on "Add binding" to bind an existing custom SSL certificate to your app. For more details, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl).

Answer (score 0):

The in the DNS for domain `sitename.com` the `A` record to  is what make http://sitename.com works.

If you want http://www.sitename.com to work you **HAVE TO** have a `www` `CNAME` record.